# How to link casper with any storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to store tests results in any storage. But unfortunately it doesn't work with any db drivers any time it raise exception "CasperError: Can't find module net":

```
var require = patchRequire(require);
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();
```

Is it possible connect casperjs to any storage (except plain files of course).

Comment: I don't think casper can do that, besides writing standard text files.

Comment: casperjs will only work with modules that don't have dependencies to nodejs. Your only option is to store test results in xunit(xml) format and use that. Alternatively you could use the 'fs' module to output the results as json or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful for people having the same challenge

The solution I ended up is writing in a file using the `fs` module of phantomjs and then executing a `redis-cli` process with the `child_process` module. My tests actually import a common module which does the job. The database script is a simple suite of redis commands, one by line. See [redis mass insertion](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert) for details on `redis-cli --pipe`.

The `runDBScript` function imported with `var runDBScript = require("dbutils").runDBScript;`

```
exports.runDBScript = function(scriptName) {
         var cp = require("child_process");
         cp.execFile('./dbscripts/exec_db_commands.sh', ["./dbscripts/" + scriptName], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
         casper.echo("Error: " + error);
         casper.echo("Stdout: " + stdout);
         casper.echo("Stderr: " + stderr);
    });
};
```

The `exec_db_commands.sh` is a very simple shell script which calls the redis client :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Executing cat $1 | redis-cli --pipe"
cat $1 | redis-cli --pipe
```